# Attaching a target group of ALB to an Auto-scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-auto-scaling

We know that in order to attach an Application/Network load balancer for an auto-scaling group, we need to attach the target group(s) to the existing Auto-scaling group in order to distribute the load. In the case of the Classic Load Balancer, we directly attach the load balancer to the `ASG` but in case of an `ALB`, we do it through the target groups consisting of targets which can be either an instance, IP or a lambda function.

My question is, are the instances in these target groups defined for an ALB and the instances in `ASG` different? Or are they the same? If they are the same, then do we have to create a new target group again with targets defined as the `EC2` instances in `ASG`? I can't understand the mapping of instances in target-groups to the instances in ASG. I went through the documentation for attaching a load balancer to an existing `ASG`, but all it says is to select an existing target group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are the instances in these target groups defined for an ALB and the instances in ASG different? Or are they the same?

They are the same.

ELB -> Target Group -> **EC2** (without ASG)

ELB -> Target Group -> ASG -> **EC2** (with ASG).

Please read the link below for details.

> If they are the same, then do we have to create a new target group
>   again with targets defined as the EC2 instances in ASG

This quote from the AWS document. We need to add ASG to ELB, then AWS takes care of the rest.

> When you use your Elastic Load Balancing load balancer with an Auto
>   Scaling group, it's not necessary to register your EC2 instances with
>   the load balancer or target group. With Elastic Load Balancing,
>   instances that are launched by your Auto Scaling group are
>   automatically registered with the load balancer or target group, and
>   instances that are terminated by your Auto Scaling group are
>   automatically deregistered from the load balancer or target group

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/autoscaling-load-balancer.html